# How do I add a search domain to Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ubuntu, networkmanager

Asked and answered for Ubuntu 10.10, but I can't get this to work for Ubuntu 11.10.  The search domain is not editable when the "Method" is "Automatic (DHCP)".  Changing the method results in a removal of all nameserver entries from resolv.conf.

Is this really as broken as it seems, or just poorly documented?

=== After upgrade to Ubuntu 12, followed this link:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/135629/how-to-add-some-additional-dns-search-domains-without-ignoring-the-ones-returned which says to add `append " x.y.org";` to /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify `/etc/dhcp3/dhclient.conf` and add `supersede domain-name "your.domain";` for substitution of the one received from dhcp or `prepend domain-name "your.domain";` to add it.

On servers receiving dhcp from ISP and loosing the internal DNS server and domain search config I removed the `resolvconf` package and edited `/etc/resolv.conf` as it was done in the past (without resolvconf package it is not anymore overwritten).

On my current machine, I edited the `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` file to include what I needed.

tbh, I'm not very happy with this new behavior (`resolvconf` overwriting resolv.conf automatically) and I couldn't find a "clean" solution yet. It is nice in certain situations and bad in others. I expect to see one nice solution here from someone smarter than me! ;)

Comment: Adding `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` worked for me.  Thanks!